# How do I write a xpath with conditions to get a list of desired webelements for my requirement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I want to get a list of webelements for which I wrote a common `xpath` to retrieve all the webelements. Problem is the list contains a webelement, which I don't require in my code.

```
List<WebElement> tbodyTD2 = InitDriver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@id='addBrandTbl']/td/table/tbody/tr/td"));
```

Which returns me 9 webelements. out of which 8 are required. 
The `xpath` for the webelement which i don't want in my list is :

```
.//*[@id='addBrandTbl']/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td
```

Is there any way to write my `xpath` so that I can get a list excluding the above element?

Comment: how add conditions in xpath to exclude a particular webelement from my list of webelements

Answer (score 2):

You can write an XPath predicate to exclude element in certain position index :

```
By.xpath("//tr[@id='addBrandTbl']/td/table/tbody/tr[position() != 3]/td")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove this element from the list

```
tbodyTD2.remove(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one    

 List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@id='addBrandTbl']/td/table/tbody/tr/td"));
    List requiredElementsList=new ArrayList();
    for (WebElement element : webElements) {
        if (!element.equals("unwantedWlement")) {
                    requiredElementsList.add(element);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got

xpath: //tr[@id='addBrandTbl']/td/table/tbody/tr/td[not(@colspan)]